# Queues and Topics in one Java Project

Tags: java, spring, jms

I want to use JMS Queues and Topics in my java Spring boot project.
So for Topics I must use this one in application.properties
`spring.jms.pub-sub-domain = true`. 
Now in the same project I want to receive queues messages too, buy ActiveMQ dont see any consumer for my queue...
How can I make it works?
Sample of my JmsListener for message send from ActiveMq localhost:8161

```
@JmsListener(destination = "FROMACTIVEMQ")
   public void getMessageFromActiveMq(TextMessage txt){
        logger.info(txt);
    }
```

What I am doing wrong? When I am using sendAndReceive method from JmsTemplate everything is going right...

Comment: You need separate listeners for queue and topic.

Comment: @duffymo I have, separate listeners in separate atComponent class, it still doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define two DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory - one for queue and one for topic - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html 30.6.1 and pass it to  @JmsListener(containerFactory = ""..)

Comment: Correct! It's works!
Did anyone know other possible option to resolve this problem?